# Using 2 languages in one speech recognition code

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am making a flashcard game for a final project and I want the user to be able to pick either english or spanish. I have created separate functions for both but how do I allow one to recognize the English and one to recognize the Spanish? I have made two Audio functions (one for english and one for spanish). I am looking to use an if then statement and want to make spanish language recognition the global variable and english recognition a local one.

I know this is tough to explain but any input would be great! Thank you all

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to guess the language just based on the audio?

Comment: We can't write your program for you. You'll need to provide code that you've tried already and ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the user to input their language of choice you can do something like:

```
while True:
    choice = raw_input("Which language would you like to use, [English] or [Spanish]?\n>>")
    if choice.lower() == "spanish" or choice.lower() == "english":
        spanish_function()
    else:
        english_function()
```

For python 3 change raw_input for input.

When you say "[I] want to make spanish language recognition the global variable and english recognition a local one" it depends on how your code is set up. You can say at the beginning of the program:

```
language = "spanish"
```

and then ask the user if they want to change that. If you have 1 function and you want to distinguish between language within it you can set a parameter default but allow the user to change it:

```
def speech_recognition(params, language="spanish")
```

A similar process can be done with classes by setting the value in `__init__()`.